# Trying to rotate several divs over top of each other

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am sorry if this is covered somewhere else but I have not been able to find it. I am trying to create an area of my page with three `<div>`s  that rotate on top of each other. I have written this css and code:

```css
#block {
 width:1202px;
 height: 402px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: auto;
}
.content {
 width:1200px;
 height:400px;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
 <div class="content">
 <a name=image1></a>
  <img src="/images/imagea.jpg" alt="image1"/>
  <a href="anotherpage.html"><img src="/images/button.png" alt="button" style="margin-left: 700px;margin-top: 300px; width:300px;height:75px;"/></a>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <a name=image2></a>
  <img src="/images/imagea.jpg" alt="image1"/>
  <a href="anotheranotherpage.html"><img src="/images/button.png" alt="button" style="margin-left: 700px;margin-top: 300px; width:300px;height:75px;"/></a>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <a name=image3></a>
  <img src="/images/imagea.jpg" alt="image1"/>
  <a href="anotheranotheranotherpage.html"><img src="/images/button.png" alt="button" style="margin-left: 700px;margin-top: 300px; width:300px;height:75px;"/></a>
 </div> 
</div>
<table style="margin: auto; width:20px;">
 <tr>
  <td><a href="#image1">&#8226</a></td>
  <td><a href="#image2">&#8226</a></td>
  <td><a href="#image3">&#8226</a></td>
 </tr>
```

I have not yet played with the formatting as right now it is just theory, but can you tell me how to make the 3 content divs rotate so that each displays for 10 seconds then moves to the next eventually rotating back to the beginning.I know this will likely require php or jquery, but I am uneducated in both.

Thank you for any help that you can offer.

Comment: http://www.jssor.com/

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what is meant by 'rotate'.  I assume cycling between div's?  One simple versatile library for this is [jquery.cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).

Comment: Hi, please try writing some javascript to accomplish your task and then post a specific question if you encounter a problem with the code you've written.

Comment: Thank you @SuperJer, that is exactly the idea I was looking for. Now I need to learn how to implement it, but I am sure google can help me with that, I just needed a direction. I really appreciate the CONSTRUCTIVE feedback.